# How to perfectly center a symbol inside a button?

Tags: html, css, typescript

In my app I have a button to expand and collapse a list. The "plus" sign means to expand the list and the "minus" to collapse it. But I seem to be unable to center the plus and minus symbols exactly in the middle of the button. Vertically they both appear in the lower part of it.

That's what I have so far:

[image: Current]

And that's what I want:

[image: Wanted]

Here is my code in CSS:

```css
.accordion-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
}

.plus::before {
    content: '\002B';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.minus::before {
    content: '\2212';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

The relevant HTML/ТypeScript part of the code:

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleAccordionClick = () => {
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
    };

return (
    <button
     className={`accordion-button ${isExpanded ? 'minus' : 'plus'}`}
                    onClick={handleAccordionClick}></button>
);
```

How can I perfectly center my "plus" and "minus" symbols? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce your problem. Can you provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can center content using flex along with justify content center and align items center or grid and place-items center. You can also use line height to help centering text if you know the element intended size.

Comment: Please add some HTML (perhaps create a functioning snippet!! using that and your CSS) so people can best assist you here.

Comment: Is my snippet accurate to your HTML?  Use the snippet tool next time.  Works very well.  anyhow, looks perfectly centered in the snippet.

Comment: @erik258 Yea, which really means this does not reproduce the issue (close it??? if it remains a such...) - so who knows what is missing.

Comment: If you're using react, why not render the content of the button using conditions in jsx instead of content in css?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this. In my snippet i've used `line-height` and `vertical-align`. I also changed the background color of the button for visual purposes.

**EDIT:** Thanks to [@Parking Master](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17202960/parking-master) for pointing out that the button text is not centered in Safari. To fix this `padding: 0` must be added to the `.accordion-button` class.

```css
.accordion-button,
.accordion-button2 {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-button2 {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

.plus::before,
.minus::before {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: sub;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.plus::before {
    content: '\002B';
}

.minus::before {
    content: '\2212';
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion-button plus"></button>
<button class="accordion-button minus"></button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="accordion-button2 plus"></button>
<button class="accordion-button2 minus"></button>
```

Comment: Lol, now it's vertically centered, but not horizontally. Best approach would be to set the parent's display as `flex` or `inline-flex`, then also set the parent's align-items and justify-content to `center`.

Comment: What do you mean it's not centered horizontally? The plus and minus symbol is centered in the middle of the button - vertically and horizontally. Tested on Chrome, FF and Opera. Or did i miss something?

Comment: on iOS it's definitely not centered horizontally

Comment: no problem, and +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to center content is using `display: grid;` and `place-items: center;` on the container element containing text.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const AButton = () => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const extraClass = 
    isExpanded ?
    "minus" : "plus";
  return (
    <button
      onClick={
        () =>
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)
      }
      className={
        "accordion-button " +
        extraClass
      }
      >
      
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AButton />
      <AButton />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App />);
```

```css
.accordion-button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    
    display: inline-grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.plus::before {
    content: '\002B';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.minus::before {
    content: '\2212';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Also you could use react to control text content instead of having it be part of a pseudo element in css like so

```js
const {useState} = React;

const AButton = () => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const extraClass = 
    isExpanded ?
    "minus" : "plus";
  return (
    <button
      onClick={
        () =>
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)
      }
      className={
        "accordion-button " +
        extraClass
      }
      >
      { isExpanded ? "−" : "+" }
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AButton />
      <AButton />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App />);
```

```css
.accordion-button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    
    display: inline-grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```